# Bootstrap Jumbotron not becoming full width of Body

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi I am trying to fix my Jumbotron to be full width of the screen but somehow it need a `15px padding-left, padding-right`. If I remove the padding the horizontal scrollbar appears with a `30px right margin`. I am using the default Bootstrap ver 3.0.3 and default VS2013 layout. As per this [link](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#jumbotron) I removed the Jumbotron outside all `.container` my page looks sth like this

```
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">.... Navigation stuff</div>
<div class="jumbotron specialjum">
<div class="over container body-content">
....page headers and other stuff
</div>
</div>
<p class="just container body-content">
... body text
</p>
</body>
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
body {
padding-top: 50px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
/*background:url("../Images/ps_neutral.png") repeat;*/
}
                    
/* Set padding to keep content from hitting the edges */
.body-content {
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 15px;
}
.just {
text-align: justify;
}
.specialjum {
background: url('http://fc00.deviantart.net/fs70/i/2013/339/7/1/princess_kenny_korosu_by_theshadowstone-d6wu2zo.png') center;
color:#fff;
background-size: cover; 
}
```

**Edit:**
Firefox + Chrome + IE10 results  ===|================|===

Any Ideas on how to fix the layout? I haven't touch the Bootstrap CSS which I updated using Nuget.

Comment: Have you tried adding the class `container-fluid` to the jumbotron div?

Comment: I tried its not working.

Comment: .container-fluid is not in 3.0.3 it's in 3.1.0

Comment: Take a look at your page in a different browser, too.  It could be some default markup added by whatever browser you're working in, although the normalize.css file in bootstrap 3 should take care of that.

Comment: @Jerreck its the same in all browsers look at my edit to see what is happening.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/aGoBUYob/1/ this doesn't add scroll bars

Comment: your code is fine, there's something else going on. http://jsbin.com/aGoBUYob/1/edit

Comment: @FloodGravemind I agree with cab.  Could you post the rest of your markup?

Comment: Also, read this thread: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10711

Comment: Hi guys I found a solution. But don't know why it works. See my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was simple. This is how I div it:

```
    <body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">.... Navigation stuff</div>
    <div> <===================this Div wrapping jumbotron
    <div class="jumbotron specialjum">
    <div class="over container body-content">
    ....page headers and other stuff
    </div>
    </div>
    <p class="just container body-content">
    ... body text
    </p>
    </div>
    </body>
```

No changes to any part of the CSS. I don't know why it works, but it just works.

Comment: It works because the createors of bootstrap are smart!  From the bootstrap docs "To make the jumbotron full width, and without rounded corners, place it outside all .containers and instead add a .container within."  http://getbootstrap.com/components/#jumbotron

Answer (score 6):

Just to share my experience after creating an MVC web application in Visual Studio 2013 I could not get the jumbotron to stretch the width of the screen no matter what I did.  I ultimately found that it was being blocked by a default **container body-content tag on the Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml page.  After removing the tag it displayed correctly. Hope that helps anyone with a similar situation to mine.

[image: Code]

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Answer (score 2):

If you're just trying to remove the padding, then you'll want to put `padding:0;` in your `.specialjum` and make sure that the custom stylesheet is called after bootstrap. Otherwise add `padding:0!important;` if it needs to be called before. Also repeat this for `margin-right:` and add in `width:100%;` if it isn't stretching to the width of the page which I believe it should already.

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/8377/) jsFiddle

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else that may end up here I have an alternative solution. I ran into this problem, but I just couldn't take my Jumbotron outside of it's container. What I did is just wrapped it in a `<div class="row"></div>`.
I'm still learning bootstrap so I don't know if this will cause any problems down the road, but for now it works pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make the **jumbotron** full width, and without rounded corners, place it **outside all .containers** and instead add a .container within.

Answer (score 1):

Another option in _Layout.cshtml (Where "Home" is the page you want to be full width):

```
@if (ViewData["Title"].Equals("Home"))
{
    @RenderBody()
}
else
{
    <div class="container container-main">
        <main role="main">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change width of `.container` to 100%:

```
container { width: 100% }
```