# ASP .Net MVC Web Application integrating bootstrap templates

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I know I will probably get too many down votes for this question, but I just could not find a tutorial to my problem.

I have created a ASP .Net MVC project in Visual Studio 2013 (New Project -> ASP.NET Web Application -> MVC) and I am trying to change the default bootstrap for this project, I have downloaded bootstrap templates from different websites but I just can not use them in my project. I have followed a few questions on SO and some tutorials but all I could was change some styling, not entirely use the template I want to use.

**Tutorial that I read:**

http://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/dot-net/bootstrap-with-asp-net-mvc-4-step-by-step

http://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/dot-net/bootstrap-3-with-asp-net-mvc-5

**SO Questions:**

[bootstrap 3 template change mvc5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22211138/bootstrap-3-template-change-mvc5)

[Bootstrap Jumbotron not becoming full width of Body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20860982/bootstrap-jumbotron-not-becoming-full-width-of-body)

After reading above questions and a few more tutorials here and there, I was able to change the theme but not the template, I want to use a parallax theme like this [one](http://www.bootply.com/100702)

I copied the css into `bootstrap.css`, javascript into `bootstrap.js` and HTML into my page Home page but then `_Layout.cshtml` is messing up the display...

**My Questions:**

1.) Am I doing this the wrong way?

2.) What changes should I make to the `_Layout.cshtml` file to display the template properly?

3.) I read that there are different versions of bootstraps, the default version that is used in the project when I created it is V3.0.0 and some templates that I downloaded are V3.1.1, Will they be compatible? I followed [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/) to upgrade the bootstrap version of my project to V3.1.1 after that some more .js and .css files were added to my project and things got more complicated.

4.) What will be the `_Layout.cshtml` file if I use bootstrap V3.0.2 ?

Any help will be appreciated...

**EDIT:**

I am trying to use this template:

[Template](http://www.bootply.com/100702)

[Template](http://bootstrapzero.com/bootstrap-template/happy-scroll)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Integrating Bootstrap Template into ASP .Net MVC 5:

1. First of all create a new Project:

   `Web Application -> MVC`
   [image]
   [image]
2. Run your Project by pressing `F5`, it will look like:
   [image]
3. Now check that your downloaded Bootstrap Template Folder contains following:

   - **`css (Folder):`**

     - `bootstrap.css`
     - `bootstrap.min.css`
   - **`js (Folder):`**

     - `bootstrap.js`
     - `bootstrap.min.js`

   <sub>Note: Sometime `bootstrap.css` may be named as `style.css` and `bootstrap.js` may be named as `style.js`</sub>
4. You will be making changes to following files in ASP .Net MVC Project:

   - `bootstrap.css`
   - `boostrap.min.css`
   - `bootstrap.js`
   - `bootstrap.min.js`

     [image]
5. Open your all the files mentioned above in code editor:

   [image]
6. Now do the following:

   - Copy all of the code from `bootstrap.css` (Template `css` Folder) to `bootstrap.css` (Content Folder)
   - Copy all of the code from `bootstrap.min.css` (Template `css` Folder) to `bootstrap.min.css` (Content Folder)
   - Copy all of the code from `bootstrap.js` (Template `js` Folder) to `bootstrap.js` (Scripts Folder)
   - Copy all of the code from `bootstrap.min.js` (Template `js` Folder) to `bootstrap.min.js` (Scripts Folder)
7. Now its time to adjust your `_Layout.cshtml` according to the Theme. We will be splitting the `index.html` file from the Theme folder into two parts, one part will go into `_Layout.cshtml` and one part will go into 'Index.cshtml`:

   [image]
8. Replace your `_Layout.cshtml` code with the code below:

   [_Layout.cshtml](http://pastebin.com/NtCYscvW)
9. Replace your `Index.cshtml` code with the code below:

   [Index.cshtml](http://pastebin.com/DJbC73N8)
10. Now run your Project it will be like:

    [Link](http://www.bootply.com/100702)

This is how I solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap is just the basis. A template may also add additional features in order to be rendered correctly. Things that may or may not be based upon bootstrap. It could also be an older version of Boostrap, or a newer as Boostratp has been at 3.2 for a while.

Usually, you include the main bootstrap.css first, then the css file(s) that the theme uses. Before you reference the bootstrap.js file, load jQuery. There is no set way to make your _layout.cshtml look good without

1) knowing what is wrong. We have to see the rendered code to really understand what is missing
2) What template you are attempting to apply since you may be missing the css or some elements that it uses.

Comment: I have updated the question with the layout I want to use, if you could just tell me how can I use that with the default asp.net project that would be great...

Answer (score 1):

There's a great and simple way to get everything you need to get going. Use Chrome and hit F12 to open the developer tools. Right-click over the area that displays the rendered layout and choose "Inspect Element". It will open the DOM for the entire page but will select an item within an iframe. Find the  element immediately within the iframe and right-click and select  "Copy as HTML". This will give you the layout as well as script css and script order.

The css that shows in the bootply editor window doesn't go into the bootstrap.css file. It's rendered inline into the code that I showed you how to get at but you can place it into it's own CSS file. Just make sure that CSS file is loaded after the bootstrap css file.

Just for reference, the template appears to be using Bootstrap 3.0.2, which isn't too old but isn't the most current.